# If class exist in first parent then apply CSS

Tags: class, parent, visible

If class 'hello' visible then apply some css to 'banner2' class. is it possible? Looking for CSS solution not Javascript.

```
  <div id="banner">
    <div class="hello"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner2">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to select a div based on visibility in CSS alone. You can easily use jQuery / JS, but since you don't want that I'd suggest trying out some trickery with [CSS combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp) and [the checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/), depending on how you are planning on changing the visibility of "hello".

Answer (score 0):

The option doesn't exist yet in CSS.
When Selectors 4 will be available you could do it this way:

```
.banner:has(> .hello) + .banner2
```

But as of this moment, you can only do it with javascript